# EF Core two-way navigational property with generic entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities: Tenant and Subscription. One tenant can have multiple subscriptions. A subscription one tenant. The problem is, that subscription is generic.

```
public class Subscription<TTenant> where TTenant : Tenant 
{
    public virtual TTenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

And in my tenant entity class:

```
public abstract class Tenant
{ 
    public ICollection<Subscription<Tenant>> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that EfCore throws an exception after calling `context.Database.Migrate();` because my Tenant entity has a collection of type `Subscription<Tenant>`and not `Subscription<TTenant>`.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: Here is the exact exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot use table 'directory.Subscriptions' for entity type 'Subscription<AcmeTenant>' since it is being used for entity type 'Subscription<Tenant>' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.'
```

While 'AcmeTenant' is the actual type I was using

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1 mappedTypes, String tableName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1 mappedTypes, String tableName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 databaseFacade)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at xappido.Portal.Acme.Backend.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CustomAcmeDbContext dbContext) in C:\Repos\xappido.Portal\xappido.Portal.Acme.Backend\Startup.cs:line 170
```